# Bathtub shoe doesn't have internal threads. How to replace drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I removed the bathtub waste assembly and was surprised to find neither it nor the drain shoe were threaded. A single bolt holds it in place, and there are no other parts still in the tub assembly.

[image: Bath shoe]
[image: Old wast assembly]
Am I missing something or is this just some obscure type of waste? I can't find a similar replacement anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

That's a "slip & seal" fitting. If it was functioning correctly, you might want to just clean it up and re install it because it's not a very common drain. Where are you located at? Replacing it with threaded components would involve getting underneath the tub to remove the drain pipe, hopefully you have an access panel or the tub's on a second floor where you have access from below.

Comment: Looks like a freestanding tub, so just need to pick the thing up. **Just.** Might not be too bad if it's the modern plastic type, gonna be fun if it's ceramic or cast iron. Looks modern-ish from what I can see...and the weird plastic fitting trends that way as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Good catch. Too busy looking at the part instead of the background.

Comment: Looks like the seal is torn in the hand photo, but it might have still been working OK given its a low-pressure drain and water should fall straight past this bit.

Comment: @Criggie  I thought that was just some extra sealant that was peeled off  and that the actual seal was the black rubber ring shown in the first picture.

Comment: @JACK thanks so much for the info. I'm in Australia and can't find a similar drain anywhere. You're right about the seal, but picking the tub up is going to be difficult for me, so I might have to try cleaning up the corrosion and see if that fixes it